# Using jQuery.load with RequireJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I often bootstrap widgets I write like so:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  doStuff();
});
```

This is often the case as I write widgets that are dependent on the rest of the application to be initialized.

I recently started using RequireJS and am not able to figure out how to attach a callback as in the code above.  I looked at and tried the domReady plugin however, it won't fit my use-case since the callbacks are invoked when the DOM is ready and not when all resources are loaded.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
// Using domReady (main.js):
require(['require', 'domReady'], function (require, domReady) {
    'use strict';

    domReady(function () {
        require(['app'], function (App) {
            console.log(window);
            App.initialize();
        });
    });
});

// Using jQuery (main.js)
// Note, this does not work.
require(['jquery', 'app'], function ($, App) {
    'use strict';

    $(window).load(function () {
        App.initialize();
    });
});
```

Given the above, what is the correct way to achieve using `$(window).load()` with RequireJS?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you can check [`$.holdReady()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/) method to acheive the result; so just after load jquery run

```
jQuery.holdReady(true);
```

later attach your  handlers which should run only after load with

```
jQuery(function($) {
    App.initialize();  //will run only after window.load;
}
```

and in your load handler setup:

```
jQuery(window).load(function () {
    jQuery.holdReady(false);  //fire all domready holded events
});
```

Comment: Not quite.  My issue is with passing a callback to $(window).load, which appears not to work as expected.  The example you gave delays the DOM ready call but does not wait for other resources to be loaded.

Comment: you want to hold until RequireJS  finish load scripts ? run `jQuery.holdReady(false);` in RequireJS callback on all scripts loaded, or create little watching array wich will be checked to ensure that load() and that callback is fired, when fired both, release the domready hold. Please make a little fiddle with trouble you get, because I not sure how you using load().

Comment: I want to wait, as in the example above, to call App.initialize when all resources have been loaded, not just those loaded by RequireJS.  I am writing a widget/module that will be embedded in a larger application and the widget is dependent on resources, not managed by RequireJS, to be loaded.  The existing implementation of the widget, without using RequireJS, works as expected (initializing the widget in $(window).load());

Comment: that what I meant, setup watcher, which will be called on both require callback and in window.load() both should set flag, if flag indicates that both events was fired, run your onload event handler, it will guarnatee that window.load() and required scripts both loaded.